# How to download Google doodle sounds?

Tags: google-doodle

I need to download the sound from the Google's doodle. I saw [this post on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/459471/how-to-download-google-doodle-for-offline-usage) that explains how to download a doodle for offline usage and I tried it, but the sounds are not included in the download. So, anyone knows how to download the sounds from Google's doodle?

Comment: What OS are you on? I have a work around but need this detail.

Comment: @DaveRook My OS is windows 7 and xp

Answer (score 1):

This is a work around; Download and install [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) which is a sound recording program.

Now, ensure you have the option to record "what you hear" or "stereo mix" by going to control panel, open sounds and then open the mixer. Selecting recording and select 'stereo mix'. If you're on W7 (maybe Vista) then you may have to download Realtek sound driver to get this option and then follow these steps:

1. Right click on the speaker icon in the system tray (bottom right).
2. Choose Recording Devices
3. In the empty white space, right-click and choose Show Disabled Devices. You should see Stereo Mix appear in the list.
4. Right click on Stereo Mix and choose Enable.
5. Right click on Stereo Mix again, and choose Set as Default Device.
   [Source of bullets](http://awesometoast.com/recording-what-you-hear-in-windows-7/)

Now, hit record in Audacity, and then play the Google Doodle. All system sound will be recorded (but please note, if you were, for example, to get a skype call, the ring of the skype call will also be recorded as this method of recording records 'what you hear'. Also, the volume of your system sound affects the record level so adjust as needed).

Right, the above was all from memory (other than the bullets) so let me know how it goes and sorry if instructions are not 100% accurate/clear.

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting the source of the page using Google Chrome, it looks like the sounds are all stored in this SWF file - https://www.google.com/logos/swf/halloween12.swf

If you can decompile/extract the sound files out of there, then you can get all the sound files.

Comment: Hi, do you want to try the latest doodles? I posted a question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286603/how-does-google-doodle-load-audios-without-having-download-requests

Answer (score -2):

I think, you can download that with mozilla firefox using "video download helper" addon.

Comment: Can you explain how to do so in the answer?

Comment: @y.selimdogan : don't think and say... Need a exact workaround.